# How can I cross-compile openssl for arm-none-eabi-gcc

Tags: openssl, cross-compiling, arm-none-eabi-gcc, arm-linux

I want to use the SM2 algorithm from OpenSSL on my stm32 develop board,

when I searched a method for that, I found all solutions is to compile OpenSSL by arm-none-linux-gnueabi, so I did it as described.

After getting a libcrypt.so, I want to use arm-none-eabi-ld to link the library, but errors about system happened, it seems that I can't use it with arm-none-eabi-gcc.

So, what can I do for it?

Comment: .so for sure **no**

Comment: Short answer is: nothing. `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc` is intended to target  a Linux system, `arm-none-eabi-gcc` a bare-metal (no operating system) one. You cannot use a Linux dynamic library on a `cortex-m`, which will usually  not running   Linux. I would suggest to give-up on porting openssl to a `cortex-m` ,  and rather to use `mbed-tls`  to implement  it - see an example [here](https://github.com/LJNL/SM2-mbedtls).